# Can't specify a configuration(drush.ini) for Drush

Tags: drush

I put my drush.ini into the ~/.drush/ and Drush can find it.But when I type command 'drush status' it show Drush did't use the drush.ini.But PHP application use it.Below are my drush status.

///////////////////////////////////

[root@AY130703214149Z ~]# export DRUSH_INI='/root/.drush/drush.ini'

[root@AY130703214149Z ~]# drush status

PHP executable : /opt/lamp/php/bin/php

PHP configuration : /opt/lamp/php/etc/php.ini /root/.drush/drush.ini /root/.drush/drush.ini

PHP OS : Linux

Drush version : 6.1.0

Drush configuration :

Drush alias files : /opt/lamp/php/lib/php/drush/includes/../aliases.drushrc.php

//////////////////////////////

Forgive my poor English,but I really need help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not in the PHP Configuration line that you posted above? It shows it's being sourced / read if your drush status indicates the `/root/.drush/drush.ini` path

Comment: Concur; everything seems to be working correctly above.

Comment: @chrisjlee, Thanks for your answer. But maybe I explain it not clearly. You can see the line "Drush configuration" , it didn't seem to use any configuration file. Is it mean that Drush haven't use a specified configuration file? I am afraid PHP and Drush use the same php.ini configuration may cause some unexpected problems. Waiting for your opinion. Thanks again.